# AspNet Owin Cookie authentication from mobile web view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

I am working on a MVC web app that requires authentication(Cookie) and a web api that uses token based authentication(Bearer). I also have an IOS app that communicates with the Web Api. So far everything is working fine.

Now I have to implement a new functionality on the IOS app that basically needs to show a web view and load a specific part of the web app, but that page requires authentication. The user was previously already authenticated on the IOS app, so what can I do to avoid that the user has to authenticate twice, one for the Ios app and also in the web view?

Please advice,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:
If you set the Authorization header in the same way we do it for Web Api requests (Bearer + Token) then it works. It seems that the Mvc.Authorize attribute not only check for the cookie but also for the token(in the same way the Http.Authorize does it).